# Jest - test based on global boolean

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have global boolean 'newHire' which will change the value inside 'futureCertificationsMapping' function. then 'futureCertificationsMapping'fuction will be called and based on value of 'newHire' mapping will be done.

futureDataMapper.js

```
 let newHire; //Global variable

const getWFDPerson = async (employeeId, countryKey, logger) => {
  return sendWFDRequest(eventData, logger);
};
const futurePersonMapping = async (person, personPayload, logger) => {
    const wfdRequest = await getWFDPerson(person.employeeId, person.countryKey, logger);
    newHire = false;
    if (wfdRequest instanceof wfdError) {
    logger.info('New Person - New Hire EffectiveDate Mapping');
    newHire = true;
    }};
    
const futureCertificationsMapping = async (person, certificationsPayload, logger) => {
  const payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(certificationsPayload));
  // const wfdRequest = await getWFDPerson(person.employeeId, person.countryKey, logger);

  if (newHire) {
    // New Hire Future effective date (Infotype 0000 - Action Type 01)
    if (person.effectiveDates.employmentStatus[0].actionType === '01') {
      logger.debug('New effectiveDate for Certifications');
      payload.assignments[0].effectiveDate = person.effectiveDates.employmentStatus[0].startDate;
    }
  } else {
    logger.debug('person exists: update effectiveDate for Certifications');
    payload.assignments[0].effectiveDate = person.hireDate;
  }
  return payload;
};
```

Now I want to run ynit test and testing futureCertificationsMapping
futureDataMapper.test.js:

```
        const logger = require('../../../config/logger');
        const mapper = require('../../../libs/futureData/futureDataMapper');
        jest.mock('../../../config/logger', () => ({
          info: jest.fn(),
          error: jest.fn(),
          debug: jest.fn(),
        }));
        const persons = [
            {
              "countryKey": "SE",
              "hireDate": "2022-05-01",
              "contractStartDate": "2021-01-01",
              "effectiveDates": {
                "employmentStatus": [
                  {
                    "actionType": "10",
                    "startDate": "2022-05-01",
                    "endDate": "9999-12-31"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
            ]
            
        const certificationsPayload = {
          "personIdentity": {
            "personNumber": "23539786"
          },
          "assignments": [
            {
              "certification": {
                "qualifier": "SE-Variations"
              },
              "certificationNumber": 7,
              "proficiencyLevel": {
                "qualifier": "ANY"
              },
              "effectiveDate": "2022-08-22",
              "expirationDate": "2022-05-01"
            }
          ]
        }
        
describe('Test that Certifications effectiveDate Mapping is working', () => {
            it('Test Certifications effectivedate: should not update new hire effectiveDate', async () => {
            const futurePerson = { ...persons[0] };
    const newHire = true;
            const payload = await mapper.futureCertificationsMapping(futurePerson, certificationsPayload, logger);
            expect(payload).not.toBeNull();
            expect(payload.assignments[0].effectiveDate).toEqual('2022-08-22');
          });
});
```

Test failed, test error:   expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
Expected: "2022-08-22"
Received: "2022-05-01"

it is obvious it is relatred to 'newHire' boolean, how can I ensure to pass the test when newHire = true ?